# PyQt4 - detect global mouse click

Tags: python, user-interface, mouseevent, pyqt4, global

A part of a small project I am working on involves 'calibrating' the coordinates of the screen of which to take a screen capture of.
By the 'screen', I refer to the entire desktop, not my GUI window.

The coordinates are calibrated when a QDialog window appears (which I've subclassed).
The user is prompted to click several locations on the screen.
I need the program to record the locations of all mouse clicks occuring anywhere on the screen - ones that don't natively trigger a QDialog mouseEvent, since they are outside this window.

Obviously overwriting the mouseEvent method does not work, since the QDialog doesn't recieve the clicks.

How can I capture global mouse clicks, so that an event is triggered and sent to the QDialog when any part of the screen is clicked?

(I'd prefer a Qt based solution, but am open to other libraries if need be).

Thanks!

Comment: The usual trick is opening a full screen frameless transparent always-on-top window and capturing mouse events with that. But it doesn't work on all Linux platforms. So it's not completely cross-platform.

Comment: Yes, I remember doing something similar in another program. I called it the 'tarp'. However, I need to allow the mouseclicks to be registered in another application as well, so I can't block the input. (I could switch off the tarp momentarily and replicate the click but that seems a convoluted and unnecessary method) Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed this isn't possible and am instead using pyHook,
letting Qt pump the messages.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you are "letting Qt pump the messages"? I am trying to implement something nearly identical but I am unsure about how to pump messages for pyHook using PyQt.

Comment: Sorry,I no longer have the code for this (and don't even remember what I was talking about)

Answer (score 3):

There are some cross-platform examples of how to do this with http://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/0.51